# Geometry and Strong inductions Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose you begin with a pile of
n
stones and split this pile into
n
piles of one stone each by successively
splitting a pile of stones into two smaller piles. Each time you split a pile you multiply the number
of stones in each of the two smaller piles you form, so that if these piles have
r
and
s
stones in them,
respectively, you compute
rs
. Show, by strong induction, that no matter how you split the piles, the
sum of the products computed at each step equals
n(n-1)/2

I dont get this because say n is 20 and i split it to 10 and 10. I multiply those two numbers together and i get 100. When i do 20(20-10)/2, i dont get 100. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That is only going to be one step in the sequence, and $10\cdot 10 = 100$ is only one of the numbers you'll add.  The next step might be to split one of the piles of $10$ into $3$ and $7$, so you'd then compute $3\cdot 7 = 21$, and then next you might split the other pile of $10$ into two piles of size $4$ and $6$, computing $4\cdot 6 = 24$, then maybe you split the pile of size $3$ into piles of size $1$ and $2$ computing $1\cdot 2 = 2$, and so on, until all the piles have size 1.  Then you add *all* the numbers you computed at each step.