# Separating piles of stones using Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Separating a pile of n stones into n piles of one stone each by successively splitting a pile of stones into two smaller piles.

Each time you split a pile you generate a number that is the result of multiplying the number of stones in each of the two smaller piles you form.

For example,  if these piles have r and s stones in them, respectively, you compute r⋅s.

For example, you may start with 4 rocks then separate them into one pile of one and one pile of three rocks; this three rock pile is then separated into one pile of one and one pile of two where the pile of two is then separated.

This sum is 3⋅1+2⋅1+1⋅1=6.

Show that no matter how you split the piles, the sum of these products from every split of n rocks to n piles of one rock always equals n(n−1)/2.

Work:

So I wrote it out as n+n-1+n-2+…+r*s=n(n−1)/2

and broke it down into LHS and RHS where;

LHS:

??

RHS:

k:

k(k-1)/2

K+1:

k+1(k)/2

=(k^2+k)/2

How do I determine what to calculate on LHS and is the purpose to make it equal to RHS?

I've looked at links below but don't understand their method of interpreting and solving.

[Pile splitting problem (Proof by induction)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355579/pile-splitting-problem-proof-by-induction)

[Fascinating induction problem with numerous interpretations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115105/fascinating-induction-problem-with-numerous-interpretations)

[Making sense of word problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585136/making-sense-of-word-problem)

[Geometry and Strong inductions Discrete Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584050/geometry-and-strong-inductions-discrete-math)

Comment: "So I wrote it out as n+n-1+n-2+…+r*s=n(n−1)/2"  Why?  Those aren't the only ways to split it.  You could just as well do $(n-r)r + ... $ so... use induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use induction.

If splitting $k \le n$ rocks always gives you $a_k=\frac {k(k-1)}2$ then

splitting $n+1$ rocks into $r$ and $s$ piles where $r+s = n+1$ will give you $a_r + a_s = r*s + \frac {r(r-1)}2 + \frac {s(s-1)}2=$

$\frac {2rs + r^2 - r + s^2 - x}2=$

Replace $s$ with $n+1 - r$ and you have

$\frac {2r(n+1-r) + r^2 - r +([n+1]-r)^2 - (n+1-r)}2=$

$\frac {2r(n+1)-2r^2 + r^2 - r +[n+1]^2-2r[n+1] + r^2 - [n+1]+r)}2=$

$\frac {[n+1]^2 - [n+1])}2=$

$\frac {(n+1)([n+1]-1)}2$.

So induction steps works.

Just need to show in works for $n = 1,2$.

If you start with $1$ you can't split them so you have $0$ and $0 = \frac {1(1-1)}2$.

And for $n= 2$ you can only split to $1$ and $1$ and $1*1 =1$.  And $1 = \frac {2(2-1)}2$.